# Shell commands fail in Rails in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have deployed on a VPS a Rails 4 application that executes shell command depending on the tasks. The app runs on Nginx with Passenger.

The situation I am having is that none of the shell commands work. After a bit of debugging, I've noticed that every command returns a "not found" error message.

For example:

```
out = %x[date 2>&1] # outputs 'sh: 1: date: not found\n'
```

why is this happening? is there some configuration setting I should set to allow shell commands in production mode? I am quite new to rails so I'm not really sure what could be causing this.

UPDATE:

Here's a bit more information, when querying from rails `whoami`, i get `www-data`, if I print the $PATH I get `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin` but then if in the command line  execute `sudo -u www-data printenv PATH` the result is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`... Does this makes any sense?

Comment: It's not a syscall, it's a shell command. And there is no `date` in the shell's `PATH` apparently. Try printing it the same way.

Comment: doing the same with the command `echo $PATH` yields `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bin\n`, while if I do it in the command line it outputs `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`, why is that?

Comment: Your shell user has a different $PATH than the ruby process.

Comment: ok but ruby (and all processes spawned by ruby) should inherit the parent processes' environment and therefore have $PATH set correctly, no? how can I fix this, I guess I could use the full path to every executable but this goes against code portability..

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Well i ended up making a method that generates a valid path according to whatever is missing in the path and then using this generated path in the command using `export PATH=path && the_command`